# Trouble with drawing with canvas Android

Tags: android, canvas, drawing

I've created a class that draws a timeline passed by addTimeline() method.
This class extends View class, and I've done override of onDraw() method. In addTimeline() there's an "invalidate()" call, so when a timeline is inserted, class will draw it. I add some timelines in an another class, that extends Activity, via "for" statement and calling addTimeline() class.

Well, only the last timeline that's created is drawn, the previously aren't showed, there's only blank space.

Is there anyone can understand why my application has this behaviour?

Thanks.

*** I'VE ADDED CODE ***

here, I insert the timeline

```
public void addTimeline(int x, int y, int totaleDurata, int distanzaIntervalli, int spessore, int color)
{
    this.totaleDurata = totaleDurata;
    this.spessoreTimeline = spessore;
    this.color = color;
    this.coordinataX = x;
    this.coordinataY = y + 10;
    this.distanzaIntervalli = distanzaIntervalli;
    setPaint();
    invalidate();
}
```

method onDraw() and setPaint()

```
private void setPaint()
{
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE); 
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    p.setColor(color);      
    p.setStrokeWidth(1);
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.CYAN);
    disegnaGrain(canvas,p);
    disegnaRettangolo(canvas,p);
    disegnaPunta(canvas,p); 
}
```

in an activity I've written this code to insert timelines

```
for(int i=1, atLeastLength = 100, x = 10, y = 30; i<=5; i++, y += 100)
{   
    setContentView(disegnoTimeline); 
    Random r = new Random();
    int randomNum = r.nextInt((550 - 100) + 1) + 100;    
    disegnoTimeline.postInvalidate();
    disegnoTimeline.addTimeline(x, y, atLeastLength + randomNum,
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us with your onDraw code and where you call invalidate?

Comment: If you just post a vague description, we can't help. How about a little bit of code or even a screenshot of the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `onDraw()` is called, you get a totally erased canvas to work with each time. So to do what you want, you need your `addTimeline` method to add a record of the timeline to some kind of array. Then in `onDraw()` you can loop through the array and draw each of the timelines.

If you need to support a huge number of timelines, you will eventually start seeing a performance hit from the `onDraw()` method having to do so much. At that point, you might consider periodically writing the canvas to a bitmap and clearing the timelines array, and just drawing the bitmap before drawing the additional timelines.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I try following your suggest!